# How do I configuring a proxy server for multisite Wordpress and rewrite urls?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have a [multipress wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite) set up on a server at `wp.aaa.bbb.edu`. This address is not publicly accessible. Each individual site's url shows up as: `wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite`, `wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite2`, `wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite3`, etc . I want one of those sites to be accessible through another url (which is public) like `aaa.bbb.edu/newsite`. When users start navigating through pages, I want them to see only that url.

For example, even though the real url may be `wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite/wp-admin` or `wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite/blog-post-title`, I want users to see those url's as `aaa.bbb.edu/newsite/wp-admin` or `aaa.bbb.edu/newsite/blog-post-title`.

On the server that has `aaa.bbb.edu/newsite`, I added this to **apache2/sites-enabled/proxy.conf**:

> <http://ip/address/for/wp.aaa.bbb.edu/*>
>
> Order deny,allow
>
> Allow from all
>
> ProxyPass /newsite http://wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite
>
> ProxyPassReverse /newsite http://wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite

This kind of acted like a redirect. When I would try to visit `wp2.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite`, I would get directed to `wp2.aaa.bbb.edu`. And `aaa.bbb.edu/newsite` was just forbidden. It wasn't a permissions issues. Any help or suggestions about mods, or a completely different approach, would be awesome. Thank you.

So essentially, I want a reverse proxy so users can access a wordpress that is not publicly available while rewriting urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the configuration on wp.aaa.bbb.edu/newsite, if you're answering aaa.bbb.edu/newsite/wp-admin as a valid answer to HTTP request in this server, you should be able to see the website. For example, I have this in a server on my network:

```
ServerName proyectos.tchile.com
     ProxyPass / http://172.18.5.17/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://172.18.5.17/
```

So, the site known as proyectos.tchile.com is on my private network. The reference is in other public Apache server.

Also, you should check a DNS config for aaa.bbb.edu, the CNAME or A answers.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean when you say "CNAME or A answers?" I'm unsure of what this is.